# Cycles renders alpha channel in black and grey instead of black and white

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a lighting setup with an HDRI map and a few supporting lights. When I render my image, my alpha channel is grey and black and I can also see that my cryptomatte channels are semi transparent. I know it is something I ticked on in my render settings...can anyone help out please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Found the solution. At some point I set my exposure to -6 which darkened everything in my scene. Located under Render Properties - Color Management - Exposure